# How do you call the integral portion that excludes the integration constants?

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology

I can find this notation which seems to be widely used:
$$
\int f(x)dx = F(x) +C
$$
Is there a notation for consecutive integrations? Something like:
$$
\int f(x)dx = F_1(x) +C_1\\
\iint f(x)dx = F_2(x) +C_1x+C_2\\
\iiint f(x)dx =  F_3(x) +\frac{C_1x^2}{2}+C_2x+C_3
$$

If so, is there a specific name/terminology and notation for functions: $$F_i(x)$$

Comment: It is a particular antiderivative. Which one we tend to commonly select is, for the most part, a matter of convention, not actual math. Occasionally, the method used to carry out the integration results in two expressions that seem to be "on the same footing" as legitimate "particular antiderivatives" but that actually do differ by a constant (even though the functional form doesn't immediately make it look like they only differ by a constant). For example you can compare $2\cos^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$. Because of this, there is probably no general notion like you describe.

Comment: They're particular solutions of the ODE $y^{(i)}=f(x)$ (at least if $f$ is continuous).